# Вывести простые числа

Tags: javascript

```js
nextPrime:
  for (var i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {

    for (var j = 2; j < i; j++) {
      if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime;
    }

    alert( i ); // простое
  }
```

В где ошибка ? 1 цикл i == 2; 2 цикл j == 2;   j < i будет false условие не выполнится(условия выполняется когда true) почему тогда выводятся простые числа ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В цикле ошибки нет, условие не проходит и в цикл не входит, просто после второго `for` сразу идёт `alert`, который и выводит число 2, потому что оно не прошло проверку деления на себя же (по той, причине, которую сами и описали). Тем более 2 - это простое число. Если вам не нужна двойка, просто начните первый цикл с 3.

```js
nextPrime:
  for (let i = 3; i <= 10; i++) {

    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
      if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime;
    }

    console.log( i ); // простое
  }
```